# CSS Dual Image Border

Tags: css, image, border

I am trying to replicate the following image border using only CSS.

http://fish.websitedesignsflorida.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/demoSlide1.png

So far I am only able to replicate it using an image border.  Is there was a way to do this strictly in CSS?

Comment: You could certainly do it with separate container DIVs, border radius, and some careful positioning. The question is can it be done cleanly?

Answer (score 0):

The two effects you need are multiple borders and rounded corners.

You can simulate as many borders as you like using box-shadow, which is well supported today. Each box shadow overlaps, so to get more box shadows make them bigger and bigger. To get the rounded corners just use border-radius.

http://caniuse.com/css-boxshadow

```
html
<img>

css
img {
box-shadow:
    0 0 0 10px #921808,
    0 0 0 20px #163459;
border-radius: 20px;
}
```

You can also use padding and a background color to get an extra border. Note this will only appear to be a border because the image is covering up the inside of the shape.

```
html
<img>

css
img {
padding: 5px;
background: #921808;
border: 5px solid #163459;
}
```

There are even more ways to do this with CSS, check out this CSS-Tricks Link:
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/rounded-corners/

Answer (score 0):

If your image position is fixed then you can use the property `position: absolute` for the borders of your image. Try this:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.d1
{
width: 200px;
height: 300px;
border: 10px solid #ff0000;
border-radius: 6px;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
}
.d2
{
width: 200px;
height: 300px;
border: 10px solid #000000;
border-radius: 6px;
position: absolute;
top: 5px;
left: 5px;
}
.i
{
width:200px;
height: 300px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<img src="first.png" class="i">
<div class="d1"></div><div class="d2"></div></body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps